# Accessing stored procedures with robconery / massive?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, subsonic2.2, massive, table-valued-parameters

[Another great article](http://rob.conery.io/2011/02/16/massive-400-lines-of-data-access-happiness/) by Rob on the [Massive ORM](https://github.com/robconery/massive).  What I haven't been able to find is references on how to access stored procedures.  [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) had some issues with the overhead of using ActiveRecords, so I preferred to do data access with stored procedures, still using the SubSonic ORM.

What I haven't yet seen is outright support for things like SQL Server's TVP's in an ORM, so I  [modified SubSonic](http://subsonic23tvp.codeplex.com/) (shameless plug) to support them.

Is it possible to access SQL Server sprocs with Massive.  Secondly, is there TVP support?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stored procedures are not specially supported, but because you can execute basically any SQL with Massive they will just work:

Sample from the [Massive Update 2](http://rob.conery.io/2011/02/20/massive-update-number-2/) article:

```
var orders = tbl.Query("CustOrdersOrders @0", "ALFKI");
foreach (var item in orders) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.OrderID);
}
```

And if your main focus is on stored procedures there is even a Micro ORM comparison article about it: [MicroORMs for .NET: Stored Procedures](http://yobriefca.se/blog/2011/06/17/microorms-for-net-stored-procedures/)